# Difference between two values in a list of tuples

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list of tuples, each representing a date and an an associated value for that day. For example

```
team_effort = [('2012-09-10', 27), ('2012-09-11', 28), 
               ('2012-09-12', 28), ('2012-09-13', 31), ('2012-09-14', 31)]
```

I need to calculate the difference in value between each day, and return a similar list of tuples each with a date and value (0 if the value is the same or has decreased, or the difference if it has increased)

So in this example I want to return

```
[('2012-09-10', 0), ('2012-09-11', 1), 
 ('2012-09-12', 0), ('2012-09-13', 3), ('2012-09-14', 0)]
```

The following list comprehension works (in 2.4+)

```
[(data[0], 0) if i == 0
    else (data[0], data[1] - team_effort[i-1][1]) if data[1] > team_effort[i-1][1]
    else (data[0], 0)
    for i, data in enumerate(team_effort)]
```

But I think there could be a more elegant solution? Any suggestions?

Note I have to treat effort_data[0] differently, as it will always be zero and if it got to the effort_data[i-1][1] line, it would look at the last item in the list (aka effort_data[-1][1].

Comment: Forgot a '(' on the first item

Comment: Chained ternary operations are very hard to read and understand.

Answer (score 1):

```
print (
    [(team_effort[0][0], 0)] +
    [(date[0], max(date[1] - prev_date[1], 0))
        for date, prev_date in zip(team_effort[1:], team_effort[:-1])])
```

Answer (score 1):

This first revision is an attempt to make the logic specification clear.

```
increases = []
for i, data in enumerate(effort_data):
    if i == 0:
        # can't increase with no prior
        increases.append((data[0], 0))
        continue
    prior_effort = effort_data[i-1][1]
    if data[1] > prior_effort:
        increases.append((data[0], data[1] - prior_effort))
    else:
        increases.append((data[0], 0))
```

actually, compared with the one-liners others have posted, I'll let this stand. Simple is better than complex. Readability counts.

Answer (score 1):

```
team_effort = [('2012-09-10', 27), ('2012-09-11', 28), 
               ('2012-09-12', 28), ('2012-09-13', 31), ('2012-09-14', 31)]

numbers = [b for a,b in team_effort]
#[0] because first item has no previous item to subtract from
differences = [0]+[max(b - a,0) for a,b in zip(numbers,numbers[1:])]
print [(a,c) for ((a,b),c) in zip(team_effort, differences)]
#=> [('2012-09-10', 0), ('2012-09-11', 1), ('2012-09-12', 0), ('2012-09-13', 3), ('2012-09-14', 0)]
```

You could do this in one line, but I think splitting this out makes it easier to read. This is the one-liner:

```
[(team_effort[0][0],0)]+[(c, max(d-b,0)) for (a,b),(c,d) in zip(team_effort,team_effort[1:])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. I think this is very readable

```
team_effort = [('2012-09-10', 27), ('2012-09-11', 28), ('2012-09-12', 28), ('2012-09-13', 31), ('2012-09-14', 31)]

result = []
result.append(( team_effort[0][0], 0) )
for i in range(1, len(team_effort)):

    last_value = team_effort[i-1][1]
    current_value = team_effort[i][1]
    if current_value > last_value:
        result.append(( team_effort[i][0] , current_value - last_value) )
    else:
        result.append(( team_effort[i][0] , 0) )

print result
```

Comment: Whilst this is very readable, it's not very Pythonic, a list comprehension would definitely be better

Answer (score 0):

```
z = zip(team_effort, team_effort[1:])
[(team_effort[0][0], 0)] +
[(d, v2 - v1 if v2 > v1 else 0) for (_, v1), (d, v2) in z]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplifiy it using `enumerate` and a special condition for the first element:

```
l = team_effort
[(j[0],0) if i==0 else (j[0],max(0,l[i][1]-l[i-1][1])) for i,j in enumerate(l)]
```

If it is the first item (`i==0`) it will add `(date,0)`.

For the next items it will compare the difference `i` with `i-1` and use it only if it is higher than zero, through the `max()` function.

```
#[('2012-09-10', 0),
# ('2012-09-11', 1),
# ('2012-09-12', 0),
# ('2012-09-13', 3),
# ('2012-09-14', 0)]
```

Comment: Note OP asked for list of tuples, this is a list of lists.

Comment: @Marcin added more description! Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: @SaulloCastro The code itself is cryptic. Imagine coming across this in a module written by someone else - you'd want to pull a pencil out and create a diagram, or translate to an explicit loop.